# Makumba - select first value in a subset

Tags: makumba

I'm trying to select the latest activity organised by an LBG for all LBGs.

currently my code looks like this:

```
  <mak:list from="r2.lbgs l" orderBy="l.lbg.name" where="l.toDate = nil and l.lbg.status = 2">
    <tr>
      <td><mak:value expr="l.lbg.name" /></td>
      <td>
      <mak:list from="best.johnny.Activity a" where="a.lbg = l.lbg" orderBy="a.end desc">
        <c:if test="${mak:count()==1}">
          <mak:value expr="a.season.name" />
        </c:if>
      </mak:list>
      </td>
      <td>
      <mak:list from="best.johnny.Activity a" where="a.lbg = l.lbg and a.isLearningEventStamped = 0" orderBy="a.end desc">
        <c:if test="${mak:count()==1}">
          <mak:value expr="a.season.name" />
        </c:if>
      </mak:list>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </mak:list>
```

I wanted to ask if makumba is "clever" enough and retrieves only the first entry, or if the whole set get enumerated. First case would be awesome, otherwise is there any more sufficient way of doing this? - I couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is, for now, the only way since you have a nested list. As it says in the [documentation](http://www.makumba.org/page/ListTag) there is a limit attribute, but it only works for the first list.

Comment: I tried to use limit as well...

I've also seen there are function you can define in mdd files, which limitations do they have? Could it be done with such a function?